# How to teach new practice to people who aren't really interested?

Tags: united-kingdom, tech-industry

I work in IT in the UK. I was hired one year and a half ago to introduce to a "new" practice to a team. 
I am in a "fixed timed" contract, therefore I can't leave for now, at least not before the contract ends (for many reasons). 
My problem: I'm exhausted trying to teach that new practice to people who aren't really interested in learning it.

This new practice isn't just in my company, but something that has become an industry standard, or at least "you should have some idea about it". It isn't actually in the requirements to become a dev (or senior dev) for my team.

I have used those methods:

- started writing a wiki with their questions and the answers to it. I have asked them to review it and well, they haven't.
- asked the "oh okay, what have you tried before?" (usually followed by "you know best so I thought I would ask you directly").

It has come to a point where I and the lead have to cover for more work than we should, and almost become the "IT support".

I understand the process of learning. It takes time. And most of the people in the team aren't exactly people who like to talk. My problem is that I feel they just don't "care" and don't really want to learn.
I would be fine if they wanted to learn but had some difficulties.

So I know what you are thinking: why push that new culture if they don't care for it? Wrong choice of hire? I am not saying the devs are the only one to blame (I would say a trio of me, the company and them).

I don't know how to "make it better", how to motivate them to learn when I know they are already struggling with their own stack. I would appreciate your recommendations (please refrain from saying "just quit now" or "it's company's fault for trying to push changes").

Comment: i am confused: who hired you "to teach devops", do you have a boss who set that goal? How do they measure success? What is your mandate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I currently lead the DevOps team in a company that was full of devs doing cowboy coding before I arrived so I get where your coming from, and the way I found that works best is to give them the tools needed to learn (Wiki/documentation, CI/CD tools, etc) then be a bit stricter then they would like with what your willing to support.

For instance if a developer comes to me with a question I know the answer is in the documentation/wiki my answer will be "You can find the answer in X documentation", if they say the documentation isn't clear I'll sit with them on the documentation to understand what isn't clear but will then open a Jira ticket for them to document the parts that wasn't clear for them for future asks on the subject.

Basically give the tools and show them how to use them then only assist them in using said tools, never ever use them for them... if the question has been answered before and was documented simply refuse to answer it in any way other then pointing them to where the answer was documented before.

The reason they prefer asking you rather then looking in the documentation is because it's easier for them, once your answer becomes "read the docs" and you don't budge from it over time they will learn that the easier answer is to start off by reading the documentation, it's not nice (or fun) but it works.

Comment: I see what you mean... I will use the "check the docs" method now!